# JavaFX in jdk 1.8.0-91 get green and half GUI in 16-bit color Windows 7 x64

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, remote-desktop

JavaFX in jdk 1.8.0-91 get green and half GUI in 16-bit color Windows 7 x64

When i login my host with windows remote desktop, the color is limited to 16-bit and the JavaFX functions unexpected.

I write a simple example from websites, as follows:

```
import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;  
import javafx.scene.Parent;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class FXMLExample extends Application{    
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {  
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));           
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);  
        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");  
        stage.setScene(scene);  
        stage.show();    
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);  
    }        
}
```

the fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?language javascript?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">        
        <padding>  
            <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25" />  
        </padding>
      <Text id="welcome-text" text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0"  
            GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />  

        <Label text="User Name:" GridPane.columnIndex="0"  
            GridPane.rowIndex="1" />  

        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />  

        <Label text="Password:" GridPane.columnIndex="0"  
            GridPane.rowIndex="2" />  

        <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="1"  
            GridPane.rowIndex="2" />  

        <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" GridPane.columnIndex="1"  
            GridPane.rowIndex="4">  
            <Button text="Sign In"/>  
        </HBox>  

        <Text fx:id="actiontarget" GridPane.columnIndex="0"  
            GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />  

    </GridPane>
```

The displayed gui looks like:
[green masked and half compressed javafx in 16-bit color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJFXB.png)
It seems that the gui is masked by a green glass, and compressed into the left part.
And in the application, the button can only be clicked in its original position.

jdk version 1.8.0_91-b14

javafx version 8.0.91-b14

What happened to the simple example in 16-bit color windows? How can i remove it with the 
limitation of 16-bit color remote desktop connection.

Comment: Can you provide some more information like: Does this also happen when not using though remote desktop and with different JDK version?

Comment: In other JDK versions this will happen, so dose the openJDK and openJFX. The main reason is that i use Remote Desktop to connect to the host. I guess that's because the JavaFX uses some openGL 2.0 functions to draw its graphic elements. The RDP in windows only supports openGL 1.1.

Comment: When i run the program in Windows 10 x64, it functions correctly in the remote desktop with 16 bit color limitation.